# Writing lists to a csv file, not writing as desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, writer

When I run this code, each list item is being separated into individual letters and separated via commas.

For example if I have the list `stockName` holding `'amazon'` and tickerName holding `'amzn'` as the first item in each of their respected lists, running the code below stores it as:

```
a,m,a,z,o,n
a,m,z,n
```

When in reality I want it on a single row as:

```
amazon,amzn
```

Code:

```
with open('/Users/reubenmcqueen/Desktop/csvStoreFile.csv', 'w',) as myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    for a in range(0, len(stockName)):
        i = [stockName[a], tickerName[a]]
        writer.writerows(i)
```

Comment: Show your lists... because what you say it's happening it'd mean that your list are just strings.

Comment: Change `writer.writerows(i)` (plural) to `writer.writerow(i)` (singular).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [writer.writerow(...)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow)

```
stockName = ['amazon', 'apple']
tickerName = ['amzn', 'aapl']

with open('test.csv', 'w',) as myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    for stock, ticker in zip(stockName, tickerName):
        writer.writerow([stock, ticker])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `writer.writerow(a,b)` like that:

```
data = ['amazon','amzn']
with open('art_ton_prices.csv','a') as test:
    writer = csv.writer(test)
    writer.writerow(data[0], data[1])
```

Comment: There is a ] missing. Why not to do just `writer.writerow(data)`?

Comment: test.close() is not needed - the `with open (...) as ...:` takes care of closing even if exceptions happen as soon as you leave the scoped block

Comment: `stockName` and `tickerName` should be different lists.

Comment: ] was not missing, intial [ was a typo, corrected it. Thanks for clarifying thing about 'with open .. as..' construction, fixed post accordingly